# Mysql where clause for different timezones

Tags: mysql, timezone, where-clause

I have the following query where i am trying to retrieve data coming in from various timezones.

So while generating a daily report, i need to pull in data with various time values according to the each timezones.

Since the table i am pulling data is fairly huge and there are about 20+ different timezone elements, just asking for suggestions of a more efficient way of writing this query.

Thanks for your help.

```
insert into ".$DailyTable." (".$DailyColList.")"." select ".$HourlyColList." from ".$HourlyTable." where 

(NE_NAME='abc1' and EVENT_TIME between '2014-12-22 00:00:00' AND '2014-12-22 23:00:00') OR !!Comment->[CST]
(NE_NAME='abc2' and EVENT_TIME between '2014-12-21 23:00:00' AND '2014-12-22 22:00:00') OR !!Comment->[EST]
(NE_NAME='abc3' and EVENT_TIME between '2014-12-21 22:00:00' AND '2014-12-22 21:00:00') OR !!Comment->[AST]
(NE_NAME='abc4' and EVENT_TIME between '2014-12-22 00:00:00' AND '2014-12-22 23:00:00') OR !!Comment->[PST]
.
.
.
.
.
.
(NE_NAME='abc22' and EVENT_TIME between '2014-12-22 00:00:00' AND '2014-12-22 23:00:00')

 group by ".$GroupBy
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. Is the time interval you're referring to identical for all OR clauses? If you could potentially write a UTC query and get rid of the OR clauses?

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea what you're tryng to do.

Comment: the time clause is different for each OR clause...for additional clarity i mentioned [CST],[EST] etc but thats causing confusion i guess

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need is to convert all dates to uniform state such as GMT. So you need to have EVENT_TIME field to be converted into GMT, or to have additional field that contain GMT. User-defined function is ok, but inefficient since queries using it wouldn't use indexes. Also, an auxiliary digest table with "name"-"timezone offset" mapping can help, just inner join it on NE_NAME, add offset to EVENT_TIME and use result in BETWEEN clause (as inefficient as function)